# DataRow in asp.net shows error

Tags: asp.net

I have code where i, gettin the values inside a table to a datarow and then further copying it to the datatable.

```
DataRow[] dr = datatable.Select("Name=Name");
document = dr.CopyToDataTable()
```

where datatable is object of DataTable
and document also is a DataTable where the values of the column "Name" are store. which i further bind inside DropDownList.

it worked fine. But suddenly im starting to get error as "Object reference not set to instance of an object.

Is there anything possible i can do?

Comment: do the 2 datatables having same structure?

Comment: add your datatable to a session.

Comment: No "document" is the datatable which im using in the datalayer, whose value ill pass to the UI. currently the datatable "document" is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
DataRow[] dr = datatable.Select("Name='Name'");
if(dr.Length!=0)
{
  //
}
```